# complete a removal after "object.user_clear()"

Tags: python

After a call to remove an object:

```
bpy.data.objects["Plane"].user_clear()
```

how do I get a refresh so that the object is no longer in my scene?  I still see the object in my scene, although the object property name show a red background in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Consult the docs.**

AFAICT you are under the wrong impression of what user clear does.

> **[user_clear()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html?highlight=user_clear#bpy.types.ID.user_clear)**
>
> Clear the user count of a data-block so its not saved, on reload the
> data will be removed
>
> This function is for advanced use only, misuse can crash blender since
> the user count is used to prevent data being removed when it is used.

reload, being when the blend file is saved,  and reloaded.

Comment: Actually I did realize this, and am looking for an alternative to actually remove(), unlink() or whatever....